# Layered Collapsible Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to replicate this side layered collapsible navigation on our website. This site is built using Magento, but does anyone know where I will be able to find this extension that was used to create the side column layered navigation on this site http://www.tightsplease.co.uk/tpgb/tights-online.html ?

I’m assuming it was a free or paid extension.

I have also attached a screenshot to hopefully explain exactly what I mean http://iforce.co.nz/i/35bdmjvl.lle.jpg I also like the way they did the price search.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Amasty Improved Navigation Pro
https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

It's not free, but worth the price.

Comment: We're using this plugin in almost every Magento website, it's really worth the price!

Answer (score 2):

try this in your `catalog/layer/view.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                    $(".block-layered-nav dt").click(function(){
                        if($(this).next("dd").css("display") == "none"){
                            $(this).next("dd").slideDown(1000);
                            $(this).removeClass("closed");
                        } else {
                            $(this).next("dd").slideUp(1000);
                            $(this).addClass("closed");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Can this open with all in collapsed position except the first one?  And what would be the css to display to the user, click to open or collapse?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at the end of *catalog/layer/view.phtml* file.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd").hide();
        jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt").click(function(){
            jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
            jQuery(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

No need to spend money with simple features...
Hope this helps

Comment: Great solution.  How can you add css to display, click to open?

Comment: this option don;t let the expanded box close!

Answer (score 0):

This Works like Charm

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not()").hide();
$("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").addClass('selected'); 
$("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function(){
            $("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown("slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add more details as to how it works?

Comment: Add this here 
/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml